# Receive a 500 error when calling staticmap

Tags: api, google-maps

We use the Google Maps API to render maps within our Web Application.

We have noticed that some calls to the staticmap API results in a 500 error.
We do not know what the root cause is, but we have found from testing that changing the Zoom level from 17 to 16 results in the correct behavior.

I would have expected a 400 (bad request) with some details as to the cause.

Can we determine what is the actual error so we can be sure we can prevent this from occurring in the future?

**Repro steps;**

1. Create a URL to the following Map with the correct Key and Signing
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.875465604245,151.193865708471&zoom=17&key=YOURKEY&size=2048x2048&maptype=roadmap&signature=YOURSIG
2. Load the Map in the Browser

**Expected:**
The Map loads correctly

**Actual:**
500. That’s an error.
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it. That’s all we know.

Notes:
Regenerating the same Map with a different Zoom level (16 instead of 17) results in the Map loading.
eg.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.875465604245,151.193865708471&zoom=16&key=YOURKEY&size=2048x2048&maptype=roadmap&signature=YOURSIG

Update:
After reviewing the comments I have further tested this and it seems the issue is now more intermittent.
However, I am still able to reproduce it after clearing the cache, but it does not seem to occur as regularly as it did before.
[500 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sIrF.png)

Comment: Works fine for me with a valid API key (and no signature).

Comment: also works for me with my key and no signature.